# How use SUMIFS based on another sheet in conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, sumifs

I have google sheets with 2 sheets and I would like to use conditional formatting with SUMIFS based on the second sheet.
Unfortunately, I didn't find the way to do it

[Link for Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gJc-BMfyrzlly1OEzOltZJo8ApWFqufUjtM0kwobvp4/edit?usp=sharing), I would like to mark in Green the column D in Sheet2 if the value is equal to the SUMIFS result

** I'm searching solution without using the Column E in Sheet2

I'll appreciate any help here

I was trying use the SUMIFS in the conditional formatting without result.
Tried also FILTER(Sheet1!D:D, Sheet1!A:A=A2,Sheet1!B:B=B2, Sheet1!C:C=C2) and still nothing

Using MATCH function isn't suitable to my needs because I need to copy the conditional formatting to all rows. MATCH will cause I need to edit each row formula.

Comment: Your sheet is not accessible. Give edit permission.

Comment: @Harun24hr Sorry, my mistake. I opened it to read only access. Thank you very much for trying help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

- *Apply to range*: `D2:D`
- *custom formula*:

`=len(D2)*(D2=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D:D"), INDIRECT("Sheet1!A:A"), A2, INDIRECT("Sheet1!B:B"), B2, INDIRECT("Sheet1!C:C"), C2))`

- *also remove unused formatting rules(related to this scenario) present in the tab*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is what I needed !   Can you please explain why should I need to use the LEN function?

Comment: Well its to not color-code the blank cells